# UIScrollView Automatic ContentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to set the ContentSize of my UIScrollView automatically, but when I do it, the **frame** height of uiscrollview is not with the screenHeight as I want.

There's my code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [self.scrollGeral setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES]; 

        [self.scrollGeral setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(screenSize.size.width, [self calcularAlturaScrollView]))];
}



-(CGFloat) calcularAlturaScrollView {
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView* view in self.scrollGeral.subviews)
    {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
    }
    return scrollViewHeight;
}
```

Therefore, I'have tried to include the following line:

```
 [self.scrollGeral setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.size.width, screenSize.size.height)];
```

But if I do it, the UIScrollView 'disabled' the scroll

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with the following code:

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self.scrollGeral setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(screenSize.size.width, [self calcularAlturaScrollView]))];
}
```